# How to pass data from (front-end) .aspx to (back-end) .aspx.cs using hidden filed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to pass data from back-end to front-end and front-end to back-end so far I have tried like below

back-end to front-end :-

back-end (.aspx.cs):-

```
public string amt;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
amt = "100";
}
```

front-end (.aspx):-

```
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
var amt = "<%=amt%>";
alert(amt); // data coming
</script>
 </form>
</body>
```

The above example is working fine but while passing the value from front-end to back-end I'm getting the null("") value (for this concept I have read [this](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=203) article)

front-end to back-end :-

front-end (.aspx) :-

```
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
                var amt = "<%=amt%>";

                alert("amt :- " + amt);

                function getval() {
                    var keyid = "1234";
                    document.getElementById('key_id').value = keyid;

                    alert(document.getElementById('key_id').value);
                    alert('hit');
                    window.location.href = "http://localhost:49855/ValuePassig.aspx";
                }
                   //alert(amt);
            </script>

            <input id="key_id" runat="server" type="hidden" name="key_id_1" />
            <input type="button" id="btn" value="click" runat="server" onclick="getval()" />

 </form>
</body>
```

back-end(.aspx.cs) :-

```
 public string amt;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

amt = "100";

//I'm getting the null("") value 
//string kId = this.Request["key_id_1"];
//string kId = Request.Form["key_id_1"]; 
string kId = key_id.Value; //Initially the value come null(acceptable) and next I'm clicking on the "click" button at that time null value should not come(but coming)

Response.Write(kId);

}
```

I did my best so far to achieve this concept and I don't why I'm getting a null value because, I have followed the article also(above mentioned link) to achieve this
concept

Suggest me where I did the mistake to pass the value from front-end to back-end and how to achieve this

Please give me your best suggestions.

Note :- I have changed the code for better understanding that is button added and when I click on the button the hidden value should come back-end.

Comment: Are you missing the _<body onload="SetHiddenVariable()">_ part?

Comment: Try putting the script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Hi @Steve thanks for your comment (I have changed my code for better understanding please check `note` once)and my requirement is when the page is loaded the amt should load and next if client click on the button the `hidden` field stored data should go to `back-end` but hidden field data not coming please suggest me how to achieve his. Please help me.

Comment: Hi @VDWWD, I have tried your solution but same issue `hidden` field data is not coming to backend please suggest me how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you tried using `window.location.href = "The redirect URL with Params"`

Ex:- `window.location.href = "http://localhost:2799/xxx.aspx?param=" param"&param1="param1"";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so we want to have some value - set in code behind cs, to set/pass/have some value for use in the client side js code.

And of course in the js code, we want use of that value, and ALSO to be able to change that value, and then upon actions, or code behind, we want that value passed back to the code behind.

First up, don't use a server side expression to "set" that value for use in the js code. The reason of course then you don't have a easy way to pass back and have use of that change value in the code behind.

You can freely change the var in js code, but you really don't have a easy/nice way to get that value back to the code behind (so that <%= %> expression is a one way street to the client side.

There are a LOT of ways to do this, but probably best is to drop in a hidden field control (as per your question title)..

You can also use a hidden text box, but might as well use the hidden field.

So, lets on page load (and ONLY first page load - like all setup on the page should be inside of the !IsPostBack code block - all web pages quite much need this !IsPostBack code block).

And bonus?
the Hidden field control has automatic view state. (that means the value will persist on page post-backs).

So, lets drop in a server side button to "show" the value.

And THEN lets drop in a button (client side) to show the value, and ALSO to modify the value.

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="MyHotelName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    <h3>Server side code</h3>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdShowServer" runat="server" OnClick="cmdShowServer_Click"
        Text="Show Hotel Name" CssClass="btn" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblShow" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>


    <h3>Client side code</h3>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdShowClient" runat="server" Text="Show Hotel Name"
        OnClientClick="ShowHotel();return false" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdChangeClient" runat="server" Text="Change Hotel Name"
        OnClientClick="ChangeHotel();return false" />

    <script>

        function ShowHotel() {
            alert("Hotel name = " + $("#MyHotelName").val())
        }

        function ChangeHotel() {
            sHotelNew = prompt("Enter new hotel value")

            $("#MyHotelName").val(sHotelNew)

        }

    </script>
```

And our code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            MyHotelName.Value = "Zoo";
        }
    }

    protected void cmdShowServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblShow.Text = "Value of hotel = " + MyHotelName.Value;
    }
```

So, we now have this:
[image]

## Edit: Above used jquery.

Of course the js code above used jQuery.

however, we could assume pure js code, no jQuery.

so, the js code would then become this:

```
    <script>

        function ShowHotel() {

            sHotel = document.getElementById("MyHotelName").value
            alert("Hotel name = " + sHotel)
        }

        function ChangeHotel() {

            sHotelNew = prompt("Enter new hotel value")
            document.getElementById("MyHotelName").value = sHotelNew

        }

    </script>
```

I should also point out the "very" imprortant adding of clientidmode="static" for the hidden field. This will "prevent" asp.net system from changing the "id" used for the control, and as a result, the js code tends to be more "clean" and "easy" to reference controls.

If you don't want to use clientidmode=static for the hidden field, then the above code then becomes this:

hidden field thus is this: (no client id mode).

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="MyHotelName" runat="server" />
```

And now our code becomes this:

```
    <script>

        function ShowHotel() {

            sHotel = document.getElementById('<%= MyHotelName.ClientID %>').value
            alert("Hotel name = " + sHotel)
        }

        function ChangeHotel() {

            sHotelNew = prompt("Enter new hotel value")
            document.getElementById('<%= MyHotelName.ClientID %>').value = sHotelNew

        }
    </script>
```

So, I often will toss in a ClientIDMode="static" for the hidden field, as that makes the js code to get the hidden control less messy.